# Combine multiple filters on React Redux

Tags: reactjs, list, redux, filter, react-redux

This is my redux state:

```
people: [
  {
            id: 1,
            name: 'John',
            weight: 4500000,
            category: 'employee',
            brand: 'sony',
            sport: 'baseball',
            country: 'NZ'
        },
        {
            id: 24,
            name: 'Frank',
            weight: 7210000,
            category: 'admin',
            brand: 'sony',
            sport: 'basketball',
            country: 'Australia'
        },
        {
            id: 10,
            name : 'George',
            weight: 5800000,
            category: 'admin',
            brand: 'samsung',
            sport: 'basketball',
            country: 'NZ'
        }
]
```

**I want to filter by multiple parameters and combine these filters**, so every time I add a condition the results narrow or expand.

For example, if I want the people who play basketball from NZ, then I would obtain the complete object with id *10*.

Then, if I remove the country filter I would obtain the id *10* and *24*

What's the way of doing it?

Any idea on how to do it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: does this work? people.filter(p => p.country === 'NZ' && p.id === 10)

Comment: no, because it has to be dynamical and I have to be able to toggle these filters inside my components. Actually, I have a lot of filters, more than two. And those are separated into different components that are connected to my store. This was just a minimal example for the sake of understanding the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the same reducer you'll need to store a list of the filters which will consist of the key to filter on and the value to filter by. e.g.

```
[{ key: 'sport', value: 'basketball'}, { key: 'country', value: 'NZ'}]
```

then you just apply the filters on the list of people:

```
people.filter(person => filters.every(filter => person[filter.key] === filter.value))
```

This just checks that each person matches all of the filters

Answer (score 1):

I think use `lodash` filter works with your need and least code to write:

For filter people playing basketball and country is `NZ`. The code should look like:

```
_.filter(people, { sport:"basketball", country: "NZ" })
```

For the case you need to filter in many reducers and dont want to repeat yourself of writing these lines. You can write an ultility or adapter function like:

```
const filterByCreteria = (people, creteria) => _.filter(people, criteria);
```

You should create a list criteria objects and export it out and whenever you need just import the criterias into your component

Creteria.js

```
export const BASKET_BALL = { sport: 'basketball' };
export const NEWZELAND = { country: 'NZ' };
// Go on for other criteria
...
...
```

Iside your component you should import criteria and pass to ultility function:

```
import { BASKET_BALL, NEWZELAND} from '/path/to/Criteria.js';
// ...
const creteria = {...BASKET_BALL, ...NEWZELAND}
Utils.filterByCreteria(people, criteria);
// ...
```